# Display custom Indoor Map with clickable objects

Tags: android

I've been working on this project for the last few months and now i need to implement a custom indoor mapping system.

On short, the map will be created on a **Web Application** and then displayed on an **Android Device**.
The map will contain the walls of that place and clickable objects, nothing more.

**Something like this:**
[image]

Is there any library that could load a map from a file that contains the walls and the tables coordinates?

If not, could someone suggest me a decent way to achieve this?

Thank you!